# Why git clone from remote machine says it is not a git repository?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

On the remote machine (**ubuntu 12.04** ) I created a `test/` folder in my repo folder and inside the folder I used:

```
git init
```

Running command `ll` inside the `test` folder will show me that there's `.git` folder inside `test`.
Now I want to clone remotely from this machine on my own machine (**ubuntu 12.04**) using:

```
git clone ssh://rahil-p001@172.16.35.117/Documents/repos/test
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
rahil-p001@172.16.35.117's password: //I enter password then...
fatal: '/Documents/repos/test' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm quite new to using git and can't think of any reason that it shouldn't work.
How would you explain that error message?

Comment: You should create bare repository. Or clone `../test/.git`

Comment: @AlexeyTen no you can clone a non-bare repo as well. I only wonder if `/Documents/repos/test` is the right path or if it wasn't instead `/home/rahil-p001/Documents/repos/test`

Comment: @VonC I'll try that and will let you know. would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be explained by the fact a normal [Ubuntu distribution does not have a `/Documents`](http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.fr/2011/06/directory-structure-of-linux-system.html)

[image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vuqCDlnP_Rc/TfLv5Ql6YmI/AAAAAAAAAKE/g8oVglafrVY/s640/directory.jpg]

(See for instance "[The directory Tree](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/amd64/directory-tree.html)")

Try instead the full path ([check it with `pwd -P`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456878/6309)) of your non-bare repo:

```
git clone ssh://rahil-p001@172.16.35.117/home/rahil-p/Documents/repos/test
```

Comment: @arashmoeen Great. Don't forget that by default, you cannot push back to that (non-bare) repo. At least not until Git 2.3.0 and its new `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28257982/6309).

Comment: Aha so if I wanna push back my changes from my own local machine to the remote repo I should've made it bare using **git init --bare** ?

Comment: @arashmoeen yes, knowing that, with a bare repo, you don't see any file in it: see more at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26687327/6309.