# Why does `cd ..` reflect symlink traversal, whereas `ls ..`does not?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls, cd

```
ls ..
```

means ‘list **upper directorie**’s files and directories.’

When I changed directory following a symbolic link, `ls ..` does not follow the symblic link. It just shows the *real* upper directory.

For example, when the directory structure is as follows,

```
r ┬ a - b - sub@
  └ sub
```

(`sub@` is a symbolic link to `sub` directory)

`ls ..`command after `cd a/b/sub` gives files at `r` directory as I’m in `r/sub`. not `b` directory’s. But `cd ..` command takes me to `b` directory.

How can I use `ls` command to show files in directory `b`?

Comment: Why are you upvoting a clearly off-topic question?

Comment: @m0skit0 Shell scripting is programming. This question is overlapping betwen Super User, Unix, and Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FUZxxl, shell scripting *is* programming, which I firmly believe (as someone with a gold badge in both "bash" and "shell" here), but I'm still not convinced that this is a good fit here. This reads more as "how do basic UNIX tools behave?", as opposed to anything particularly relevant for scripted use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behavior of cd/bash on symbolic links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456784/behavior-of-cd-bash-on-symbolic-links)

Comment: @FUZxxl Nowhere in the question it is stated this is a script. And definitely the question is not about scripting but about the tools themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A directory doesn't know what symbolic link you used to get to it; `..` is an actual directory entry that points to the *real* parent directory.  But when you use the shell command `cd ..`, bash cheats. It knows what path you used to get there (it's in `$PWD`), so it just removes the last component of that and changes to the resulting directory.

You can use the same trick yourself for the benefit of other commands by using `"${PWD%/*}"` instead of `..`:

```
ls "${PWD%/*}"
```

Comment: Please don't use `${PWD%/*}`; this has several issues. Use `$(dirname $PWD)` instead.

Comment: @FUZxxl What issues? The only one I know of is the corner case where `dirname` returns `.` and the substitution will not which doesn't apply here.

Comment: @FUZxxl, if you're going to try to promote best practices, at least make it `dirname "$PWD"`. Otherwise, you're creating more bugs than you fix.

Comment: @EtanReisner Right, `$(dirname "$PWD")` is even better. The substitution does not work correctly on a path like `foo//bar` or on the root directory. It can also fail on relative paths. It also fails on `foo/bar/`. `dirname` uses a [fairly complex algorithm](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) to deal with all possible situations.

Comment: Then again, if you're going to use a subshell anyway, you could just `(cd .. && ls)`. How about a function? `symls() ( cd "$@" && ls )`? You can use it like `symls ..`, or go crazy and do `symls -P ..` to completely dereference the path.

Comment: @plhn, inside `( )`, the `cd -` is completely unnecessary; the effect of the `cd ..` goes away when the subshell it's confined to exits.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you’re right.

Comment: It would need to be `"$(dirname "$PWD")"` with double quotes around both the inner parameter expansion and the outer command substitution. It is more general, but since `PWD` is always an absolute pathname, I'm not sure how necessary it is in this case.

Comment: @FUZxxl I was inspired to try writing a shell built-in `dirname` and put it [on codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/102622/28012). I looked but couldn't find any good test data (other than in the spec link to test it with).