# symbolic links used as directory

Tags: unix, symlink

`clones` is a link

```
nrolland at mactoasty in ~
$ la clones
lrwxr-xr-x  1 nrolland  staff    11B Oct  5 16:37 clones -> Sync/clones
```

from a subdirectory

```
nrolland at mactoasty in ~/clones/monoidAsComputation/app

$ ls ../../../
```

list all the files in **~/Sync**

whereas this lists all the files in ~

```
cd ../../../; ls
```

---

If I try to point a symbolic link to a location above, that fails although I can `cd` into relative location

```
nrolland at mactoasty in ~/clones/monoidAsComputation/app
$ ln -s ../../../.emacs.d/reveal.js
```

whereas this will, because `ln` expands the `clones` symbolic link to its definition............

```
nrolland at mactoasty in ~/clones/monoidAsComputation/app
$ ln -s ../../../../.emacs.d/reveal.js
```

Is there any way to get back some sane referential transparency, or at least the same behavior between `cd` and `ln` ?

---

I use zsh, on macos. I will try with other shells

Comment: What is `la`? I do not believe that is a standard UNIX command. Do you experience the same using other shells? Which shell are you using? ps. Interesting question!

Comment: it's ls -la, using zsh.  i will precise

Comment: Read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am sure some people wrote it this way. but  how to avoid their crazy scheme is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about zsh, but the following will work for `bash`:

To get the same behaviour as `ln` (and any other command), you can use `cd -P` in `bash`. In your example, you should see:

```
# nrolland at mactoasty in ~/clones/monoidAsComputation/app
cd -P ../../..; ls
```

listing files in `~/Sync`, same as `ls ../../../` does. You can get this behaviour with simple `cd ../../..`, by aliasing:

```
alias cd='cd -P'
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456784/behavior-of-cd-bash-on-symbolic-links).