# absolute path if PWD itself is a symlink

Tags: bash, pwd, realpath, readlink

I have following folder structure created via `mkdir -p foo subdir/bar && ln -s subdir/bar bar`

```
├── bar -> subdir/bar
├── foo
└── subdir
    └── bar
```

when working in `bar` folder: How can I resolve/expand a relative path (`../foo`)?

```
user@mypc:/work/bar$ realpath -e ../foo     # result: "realpath: ../foo: No such file or directory"
user@mypc:/work/bar$ realpath -m ../foo     # result: "/work/subdir/foo"
user@mypc:/work/bar$ realpath -L ../foo     # result: "/work/subdir/foo"
user@mypc:/work/bar$ readlink ../foo        # result: ""
user@mypc:/work/bar$ readlink -f ../foo     # result: "/work/subdir/foo"
user@mypc:/work/bar$ readlink -m ../foo     # result: "/work/subdir/foo"
```

What can I do to get absolute path `/work/foo` from relative path `../foo`?

**Edit1**:
Unfortunately it even becomes more tricky if I only have a variable MYPATH which I do not know if it is relative or absolute.

```
user@mypc:/work/bar$ MYVAR="../foo"
user@mypc:/work/bar$ realpath -L "$PWD/$MYVAR"  # result: "/work/foo" 
user@mypc:/work/bar$ MYVAR="/work/foo"
user@mypc:/work/bar$ realpath -L "$PWD/$MYVAR"  # result: "realpath: /work/bar//work/foo: No such file or directory"
```

What can I do to get absolute path `/work/foo` from variable `MYPATH` (which might be set to `../foo` or `/work/foo`?

Comment: Re "when working in `bar` folder": The `foo` dir listed in your tree is actually `../../foo` relative to the current dir.

Comment: Physically yes, Logically no

Comment: But the symlink's logic only extends to (and below) `bar`. See my post how to avoid treating `..` logically.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your directory layout:

```
cd /work/bar
ls -d ../foo # Check that foo really exists
realpath ../foo # Prints /work/bar
```

If you get a *not found* error, it means that the directory really does not exist. That's why I propose to check this before.

However, your setting is a bit confusing in that you have two `bar` directories. Make sure that you apply the correct relative path when calling `realpath`.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with paths with symlinks, you need to be aware of the difference between "logical" and "physical" directory structures as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456878/3966456).

In your example, after `cd bar`, the logical directory is `/work/bar` and the physical directory is `/work/subdir/bar`. An important thing to know is that the filesystem itself only contains information about physical directory structures, and the logical directory structure is only tracked by your shell.

If you pass `../foo` as a parameter to an external process, the process can only ever resolve it to `/work/subdir/foo` because it cannot possibly know the logical directory structure which is only known by the shell. If you do `cd ..` (without `set -o physical`) instead, you are back in `/work/` instead of `/work/subdir/` because `cd` is part of the shell and can obtain the necessary info about logical directory structure.

Can we make `realpath` behave like `cd`? Yes, but we need to forward the info about logical path to the command line argument of `realpath`. The keypoint is that, `realpath -L` knows how to deal with logical paths, but above all it needs to know about the logical path, which can only be forwarded explicitly from the shell. One way to do so is via `$PWD`.

The solution to your problem is, therefore,

```
realpath -L "$PWD"/../foo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. 
Unfortunately this solution is also little bit tricky if I only have a variable `MYPATH` which I do not know if it is relative or absolute. 


`user@mypc:/work/bar$ MYVAR="../foo"`
`user@mypc:/work/bar$ realpath -L "$PWD/$MYVAR"  # result: "/work/foo"`
`user@mypc:/work/bar$ MYVAR="/work/foo"`
`user@mypc:/work/bar$ realpath -L "$PWD/$MYVAR"  # result: "realpath: /work/bar//work/foo: No such file or directory"`

Comment: You'll need an `if` for it. Just check whether the first character is a forward slash or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the symlink only extends to `bar` and everything **below** it. But `..` moves upwards, leaving the symlink's logic. Therefore, you need to configure the process that deals with `../foo` to not resolve the `..` part logically.

For example, if you wanted to `cd` into `../foo`, use its `-L` option, assuming your `cd` implements it, see some manual excerpts on `cd -L`:

- The POSIX manual describes `cd -L` as

> symbolic link components shall not be resolved before dot-dot components are processed

- Bash's `cd -L` is defined as

> the `-L` option forces symbolic links to be followed by resolving the link after processing instances of `..` in `dir`.

Therefore:

```bash
$ pwd
/home/user/work

$ tree --noreport
.
├── bar -> subdir/bar
├── foo
└── subdir
    └── bar

$ cd bar

$ pwd; pwd -P
/home/user/work/bar
/home/user/work/subdir/bar

$ mypath='../foo'

$ cd -L "$mypath"

$ pwd; pwd -P
/home/user/work/foo
/home/user/work/foo
```

Note: If you have substituted `cd` to some other implementation or script, you may want to use `builtin cd` instead.